# How do I exclude pairs of rows from being aggregated in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, aggregation

We have an audit trail of actions and I've been asked to report upon the average amount of time that these actions have taken.

Unfortunately, the audit trail contains 'cancellation' entries which, in essence, exclude the previous action.

So, some data.

```
AuditTrail
ID OrderID ActionQty ActionDate
1  1        1        2002-02-02
2  2        1        2002-02-02
3  1       -1        2003-03-03
4  1        1        2004-04-04
```

and

```
Orders
OrderID OrderDate
1       2001-01-01
2       2002-02-02
```

The base date for the comparison is the difference ActionDate.

It is the average of these that is required.

In this example above, AuditTrail entries 1 and 3 need to be excluded as entry 3 is a 'cancellation' and therefore needs to exclude the previous non-cancellation entry (entry 1).
The IDs are sequential, but not necessarily contiguous for an order as there are many orders and many audit trail entries.

Even more complicated is that we can see runs of 'cancellations', which need to rollback further down the chain.

For example

```
AuditTrail
ID   OrderID ActionQty ActionDate
1030 99       1        2002-02-02
1031 99       1        2002-02-02
1032 99      -1        2003-03-03
1033 99      -1        2004-04-04
```

In this example, 2 in and 2 out.

So.

An average is a total divided by a count. We can easily use `SUM(ActionQty)` (GROUP'd BY AuditTrail.OrderID) to get the right count for an order.

Getting the number of days for an AuditEntry is easy too (`TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, Orders.OrderDate, AuditTrail.ActionDate)`).

But excluding the right ones ... I can't work it out.

Any clues?

Comment: So in that last example, what would be the result for `The number of days for an audit entry` on order 99? Would it be `0` because effectively all audit lines have been cancelled? I guess, another way to ask is: "Given your example data, what is your desired result?"

Comment: Yeah. I did miss the expected/desired results.

OrderID 1 would be 3y3m3d (whatever that is in days).
OrderID 2 would be 0
OrderID 99 would be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match using a row number method.
given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| ID   | OrderID | ActionQty | ActionDate |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
|    1 |       1 |         1 | 2002-02-02 |
|    2 |       2 |         1 | 2002-02-02 |
|    3 |       1 |        -1 | 2003-03-03 |
|    4 |       1 |         1 | 2004-04-04 |
| 1030 |      99 |         1 | 2002-02-02 |
| 1031 |      99 |         1 | 2002-02-02 |
| 1032 |      99 |        -1 | 2003-03-03 |
| 1033 |      99 |        -1 | 2004-04-04 |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query

```
Select s.id,s.orderid,s.actionqty,s.actiondate
from
(
select t.*, 
        if(t.orderid<>@p ,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=t.orderid p
from t,(select @block:=0,@rn:=0,@p:=0) rn
where actionqty > 0
order by orderid,id
)s
left join
(
select t.*, 
        if(t.orderid<>@p ,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=t.orderid p
from t,(select @block:=0,@rn:=0,@p:=0) rn
where actionqty < 0
order by orderid,id
) cans on s.orderid = cans.orderid and s.rn = cans.rn
where cans.id is null
```

results in

```
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| id   | orderid | actionqty | actiondate |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
|    4 |       1 |         1 | 2004-04-04 |
|    2 |       2 |         1 | 2002-02-02 |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: On mysql, so no unable to reuse table `t`. :-/

Comment: Try substitute your table name for t

Comment: @RichardAQuadling - why? Is t a temporary table? As that is the main reason you cannot access a table twice in a query.